# My code works, but I don't fully understand how

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace SimpleweightConversion
{
    public class PoundstoKilos
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            double pounds = 0.0;
            Console.Write("How many pounds?  ");
            double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pounds);
            double kilograms = pounds * 0.453592;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} pounds is equal to {1} kilograms", pounds, 
            kilograms);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to learn C# and I created this code to convert from pounds to kilograms, I added the tryparse bit to avoid an error if the user throws something other than numbers at the program, and it works!.The only problem I have is it doesn't clearly show when does it assign the user's input to the pounds variable, because at the start, the value of the pounds variable is 0.0, but at some point, the value provided by the user is assigned to the pounds variable, or at least that's what I think is happening.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: Please make the title a bit more precise. Tell the community *what* is your problem not *that* you have a problem.

Comment: When you don't know what a function does, read the manual. The fastest way is putting the cursor on the function name and press F1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user's input is assigned to the `pounds` variable within the `TryParse()` method.

The `out` modifier indicates that the argument is being passed by reference - which means that any changes to the argument (in this case, `pounds`) that occur within the method call will be applied to the actual variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any way I can write this segment of my code to make it more readable? I mean to make it clear that the user's input is being assigned to the 'pounds' variable.

Comment: @John: to make it clearer, use an inline `out` variable declaration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables

Comment: @John, another option to make it clearer that you're assigning a value to `pounds` would be the `double.Parse()` method. In that case you would be able to write `pounds = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. Take note though, that you'll need to do your own error checking in that case, because if you pass an empty string to `double.Parse()` you'll end up with a run-time error.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx), the syntax for TryParse() is:

```
public static bool TryParse(
    string s,
    out double result
)
```

This means that if the string `s` is numeric, its parsed value is immediately assigned to the variable `result`.
In your code, you have the line `double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pounds);`
In this case, the input from the console is parsed to a double, and assigned to `pounds` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is get assigned when u take user's input using Console. ReadLine() method. 
"I.e. double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pounds);"
User's input is extracted into pounds variable.

Comment: use "var consoleInput = Console.ReadLine(); double.TryParse(consoleInput, out pounds); ". Set a breakpoint on double.TryParse and debug your application.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have explained your error. I thought I'd just show you how you should write your code to make it easier to understand:

```
public class PoundsToKilos
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double pounds = 0.0;
        Console.Write("How many pounds?  ");
        if (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out pounds))
        {
            //`pounds` has been assigned a value
            double kilograms = pounds * 0.453592;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} pounds is equal to {1} kilograms", pounds, kilograms);
        }
        else
        {
            //`pounds` has NOT been assigned a value
            Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid number.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```